# Office JavaScript API: track changes

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, office365-apps

I'm working on a side project using the Microsoft Office JavaScript APIs and have gotten stuck on something I don't see mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office).

Is there any way to determine if a given `Range` object has been "deleted" with Track Changes enabled? From what I can tell, depending on the version of Word, the deleted range will either be present (i.e. included when iterating over `document.body.paragraphs.items`) or not.

In my local testing, sometimes Word renders the text in red with strikethrough; but the API doesn't seem to do anything to indicate this on the object. Other times the text is removed altogether, in which case the object isn't there to begin with.

Is there any way to interact with the Track Changes feature via the API?

Comment: did you found any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to access the Track Changes feature with the Office JavaScript APIs. But it is a good idea, so please raise it at [M365 Dev Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). First search to see if someone has already made this suggestion.

Comment: currently range.text, brings back the text of the range, ignoring completely the changes made in tracked changes (deletions, additions). Is there a way to get the text, without ignoring the tracked changes, and also when doing .search(), to do it without ignoring the changes?

Comment: Can we Track Changes programmatically and manipulate them using Office JS APIs now?

Comment: @SagarMistry, No, this is still not supported.

Comment: About 4.5 years since the question was asked. The UserVoice link has long been dead. Is there any progress on this? Where can we track this issue?

Comment: We now track these kind of suggestions on the M365 Dev Platform Ideas site. I've updated my answer.